# primefaces p:column exportOnly and exportable

Tags: primefaces

I am using primefaces 3.2. And I need to use p:dataExporter. But parameters `p:column exportable="false"` and `p:column exportOnly="true"` does not works at all! What could be the reason of that?

Here is the code:

```
<p:dataExporter type="xls" target="dataTable" fileName="clients" postProcessor="#{clientBean.postProcessXLS}" />

<p:dataTable value="#{clientBean.model}" var="item" id="dataTable"
                        emptyMessage="#{messages['message.empty']}" styleClass="list"
                        paginator="true" rows="10" widgetVar="table"
                        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                        currentPageReportTemplate="(#{messages['table.page.current']}: {currentPage} #{messages['table.totalpages']} {totalPages})"
                        rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,25,50" paginatorPosition="bottom" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false">
                <p:column exportOnly="true">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{clients['clientNumber']}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.clientNumber}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column sortBy="#{item.clientNumber}"
                          exportable="false" filterStyle="display:none;">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{clients['clientNumber']}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/admin/management/clients/clientInfo.jsf">
                        <f:param name="id" value="#{item.id}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.clientNumber}" />
                    </h:outputLink>
                </p:column>
```

Comment: Where did you find `exportOnly` attribute? There is no such attribute in primefaces column tag.

Comment: I know, but - http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=24542

Comment: exportOnly is not very important for me. I need to know why exportable="false" does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `exportOnly` attribute doesn't exist at all in `p:column` tag. `exportable` attribute is introduced in version 3.4, so it doesn't exist in your version (3.2).